# Removing/resetting element added to DOM

Tags: jquery

I have made this little cursor trail app, and have a small bug I can't figure out. When you select the settings and click 'Go', it adds a div to the DOM, and is working fine. However, if you then change the settings and click 'Go' again, it adds another of these divs without removing the first one. So you end up with two (or more) coloured/sized cursor trails. How can I make it so when you click go it removes the existing trail and adds the new one?

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hh40ydky/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.go').click(function () {

    var color = $('.pointcolor').val();
    var size = $('.pointsize').val();
    var speed = parseInt($('.speed').val(), 10);

    $('.mousearea').mousemove(function (e) {

        var pointer = $('<div id="pointer">').css({
            'width': size,
            'height': size,
            'background-color': color,
            'border-radius':'100%'
        });


        $(document.body).append(pointer);

        pointer.css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            top: e.pageY + 10,
            left: e.pageX + 10
        }).fadeOut(speed);

    });
  });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems there:

1. You're creating multiple elements with the same `id`, which results in an invalid document. The good news is you have no reason to give the pointer element an `id` at all (just remove it).
2. The main problem is that your `click` handler creates a *new* `mousemove` handler every time it's clicked. So the second time, you have two handlers attached, each managing a set of pointers. The third time, you have three, etc.

   You probably only want to attach to the `mousemove` event once, *outside* your click handler, and instead use a flag for whether trails are enabled or not.

   Alternately, but I wouldn't recommend it, you could use an event namespace and remove your old handler before attaching the new one.
3. You never remove your pointer elements. `fadeOut` will make them invisible, but won't remove them. Add a callback to `fadeOut` to remove the element when it's done fading out.
4. Finally, I'd probably add a class to the pointer elements so that I could remove any that were lying around when the user clicks Go again, but that's a nice-to-have (as they'll remove themselves anyway).

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hh40ydky/2/) - In this, I'm using `color` as my flag (since it'll be a non-empty string once you've clicked Go at least once):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var color; // Using this as the flag for #2
    var size;
    var speed;

    $('.go').click(function () {

        color = $('.pointcolor').val();
        size = $('.pointsize').val();
        speed = parseInt($('.speed').val(), 10);

        $(".pointer").remove(); // #4
    });

    // Moved this out of `click` for #2
    $('.mousearea').mousemove(function (e) {
        if (!color) {
            return;
        }

        var pointer = $('<div class="pointer">').css({ // #1, #4
            'width': size,
            'height': size,
            'background-color': color,
            'border-radius':'100%'
        });

        $(document.body).append(pointer);

        pointer.css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            top: e.pageY + 10,
            left: e.pageX + 10
        }).fadeOut(speed, removeWhenDone); // #3
    });

    function removeWhenDone() {            // #3
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you for such a detailed response. Would you mind clarifying what "if (!color) {
            return;
        }" does? Just want to make sure I am understanding everything correctly, this is really just a learning exercise for me! Thank you again!

Comment: @user3623348: No worries. When you declare a variable, its default value is `undefined`. `undefined` is one of the "falsey" values -- values that coerce to `false` if you treat them as a boolean. So `if (!color)` goes into the body of the `if` if `color` contains any of the falsey values. (The falsey values are `undefined`, `null`, `""`, `0`, `NaN`, and of course, `false`.) So that line is testing whether we've ever assigned a non-empty string to `color` and, if not, returning out of the handler before we do anything.